# Can a convergent net over a countable set have a subsequence?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, order-theory

I have a rather silly question. I have a Hausdorff topological space $X$, and a countable set of continuous maps of $X$ into $X$, say $\{T_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Given a net $\{T_{b_i}\}_{i\in I}$, $b_i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$\lim_{i\in I} T_{b_i}(x)$ exists for each $x\in X$ (the limit converges in the product topology) can I reduce this limit to a subsequence (i.e. a subnet that is a sequence)?

(Especially because $b_i$ must be repeating as $\mathbb{N}$ is countable.)

Thanks!

Comment: So for my understanding: you have one common directed set $I$ such that for you have a subnet $b: I \to \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x \in X$, $T_{b(i)}(x)$ converges in $X$. You then want a subsequence instead? This is probably impossible in general.

Comment: Why is this the case? Intuitively, we only have countably many elements in the set - couldn't we somehow show that the "repeated" elements only occur reasonably many times and remove them. (Is there a counter example btw?)

Comment: Does it help if the maps go from $X$ into a metric space?

Comment: As usually defined, the indexing set of a subnet has to have a final map into the indexing set of the net. So you can have a net with no subsequences, however nicely it converges. E.g. a constant net indexed by $\omega_1$.